# Can i override the navigator getUserMedia and use my own custom modal?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, getusermedia, navigator

I'm doing a next.js application that will behave like a progressive app, it should be usable on a mobile.

I want the user to be able to take pictures with his phone from the app.

It's all working fine until now, i am just wondering if i can have my own modal for getting the user permission to use the camera from his device ?
Because as soon as i call the following method, the browser prompts its own popup alert.

```js
//....
const constraints = { 
      audio: false,
      video: true, 
    }
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function (stream) {
     // TODO handle stream
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.error(err)
    });
//....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't customize the permission request dialog but you can make a modal where you can insert and customize whatever you want and make a listener for a "grant" button where you launch the default one.